# Merge or combine (diagonal) data frames by date column

Tags: r

I have several data frames that look like the following.  The `1`, `2`, `3` columns are a forecasted quantity `n` days in the future from the `Date`.

```
Date           1     2     3
2016-02-02     100   NA    NA
2016-02-03     NA    55    NA
2016-02-04     NA    NA    75          

Date           1     2     3
2016-02-03     105   NA    NA
2016-02-04     NA    45    NA
2016-02-05     NA    NA    70

Date           1     2     3
2016-02-04     110   NA    NA
2016-02-05     NA    40    NA
2016-02-06     NA    NA    72
```

How can I merge these data frames so the resulting DF looks like this?:

```
Date           1     2     3
2016-02-02     100   NA    NA
2016-02-03     105   55    NA
2016-02-04     110   45    75
2016-02-05     NA    40    70
2016-02-06     NA    NA    72
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `data.table`, we use `rbindlist`, and then omit the `NAs` with `na.omit` by looping over the columns, grouped by the 'Date' column.

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list(df1, df2, df3))[,lapply(.SD, na.omit), Date]
#          Date  X1 X2 X3
# 1: 2016-02-02 100 NA NA
# 2: 2016-02-03 105 55 NA
# 3: 2016-02-04 110 45 75
# 4: 2016-02-05  NA 40 70
# 5: 2016-02-06  NA NA 72
```

If there are duplicate non-NA elements in 'Date' after the `rbindlist` step, we could do an average of the values.

```
rbindlist(list(df1, df2, df3))[,lapply(.SD, mean, na.rm=TRUE), Date]
```

NOTE: 'df1', 'df2', 'df3' are the data showed in the OP's post.

Answer (score 1):

Using dplyr and reshape2, we can reshape each data frame to long format, drop the NAs, stack them together, than go back to wide format:

```
> list(df1,df2,df3) %>% lapply(melt, "Date", na.rm=TRUE) %>% rbind_all()  %>% dcast(Date~variable)
        Date  v1 v2 v3
1 2016-02-02 100 NA NA
2 2016-02-03 105 55 NA
3 2016-02-04 110 45 75
4 2016-02-05  NA 40 70
5 2016-02-06  NA NA 72
```